# How to change the password in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my MODEL:

```
public function editNewPassword($data){
    // $user_name = $data['user_name'];
    $user_id = $data['id'];
    $user_oldpass = $data['password'];
    $user_newpass = $data['newpass'];


    $sql = "UPDATE user SET password = '".md5($user_newpass)."' WHERE password = 'md5($user_oldpass)' ";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
}


public function getUser(){
    return $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM 'users'");
}
```

This is my CONTROLLER:

```
function changePassword(){
        if(isset ($_POST['edit_password'])){
            $user_oldpass = ($_POST['user_oldpass']);
            $user_id = ($_POST['user_id']);
            $user_name = ($_POST['user_name']);
            $user_newpass = ($_POST['user_newpass']);

            $this->model->editNewPassword($data);
    }       
}
```

this is for my VIEW code:

```
<form role="form">
<!-- <input typ e="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Your Username"><br> -->
<input type="text" name="old_password" id="old_password" placeholder="Enter Your Old Password"><br>
<input type="text" name="new_password" id="new_password" placeholder="Enter Your New Password"><br>
<input type="text" name="con_newpassword" id="con_newmpassword" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password"><br>
<span id='message'></span>
<input type="hidden" id="edit_password_id">
<button id="edit_password" style="background-color:#008000">Submit</button>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
$('#edit_password').on('click', function(){
// alert('Password changed successfully!')
var 
user_id = $('#edit_password_id').val();
user_name = $('#username').val();
user_oldpass = $('#oldpassword').val();
user_newpass = $('#newpassword').val();


$.ajax({
url: URL+'changepassword/changePassword',
type: "post",
data: {
    id : id,
    name : name,
    password : password, 
    newpass : newpass
},
success: function(response){
    $('#edit_password_id').modal('toggle');
    location.reload();
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
});
});
```

My problem is my password won't change even no error and I don't know where is the error to my code. I am new to this.

Comment: IS this anything more than a hobby project and/or a school project? If so, there I'd advise starting from scratch because using MD5 for password hashing, no salt and updating anybody whose has matches are *fundamental* problems with a web application security. And I suspect you are open to SQL injections (even though there are none present *in this code*.

Comment: Your where clause looks wrong. Insert an echo $sql; and you will see.

Comment: Agree with @kuh-chan. In the second part of the statement, the `$user_oldpass` variable will be expanded but the `md5(` and `)` parts will be included too. The query will look for something like `md5(admin1234)` (rather than an md5 hash) and it won't match the record you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

This code here is the immediate problem:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET password = '" .
    md5($user_newpass) .
    "' WHERE password = 'md5($user_oldpass)' ";
```

For a password of "password", the database will see:

```
 UPDATE user SET password = '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'
 WHERE password = 'md5(password)'
```

I believe you want `md5()` here to be seen as a database function, but since it is in quotes, it will just be seen as an ordinary string. Since your user does not have a password of `md5(password)`, the query runs and no rows are affected.

### Related advice

- Don't use MD5 as a hashing algorithm for passwords
- Always use a salt
- Use the built-in hashing and salting functions unless you know what you're doing
- Updates to a password should filter on user and password, not just user
- Use parameter binding to avoid SQL injection